# Using the Rally SDK, how do I filter a cardboard for a tag?

Tags: javascript, rally

I would like to create a cardboard showing all the work products of a given type (user story, test case, etc.) that have a particular tag. I tried adding the following filters statement  to the storeConfig, but nothing comes up:
filters:[
{
   property:  'Tag', //also tried property: 'Tags'
   operatore: '=',
   value:     'MyTag'
}]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The work product's tags are a collection, so to filter on them, you need to use Tags.Name as the property. Once you do that your filter will do what you want.